The button under the card
I have product cards, I want to have product cards, I want to add a "Buy" button under them. But the button is constantly moving to the right. How do I put a button so that each button is under its own card? I have tried to do this in various ways, but without success.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;

  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .tokenInfo{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      .price{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #ee83e5;
        font-weight: 700;
        ins{
          margin-left: -.3rem;
          margin-right: .5rem;
        }
      }
      .duration{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #a89ec9;
        margin-right: .2rem;
        ins{
          margin: .5rem;
          margin-bottom: .4rem;
        }
      }
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}
.buttons {
    margin: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-hover {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 55px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
    background-size: 300% 100%;

    border-radius: 50px;
    moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-hover:hover {
    background-position: 100% 0;
    moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-hover:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-hover.color-7 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6253e1, #852D91, #A3A1FF, #F24645);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(126, 52, 161, 0.75);
}
<div class="product-card-container">
    <div class="nft"  onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м1.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Набор</h2>
          <p class='description'></p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>499 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<button class="btn-hover color-7">BUTTON</button>
     <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('12', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м2.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Заяц</h2>
          <p class='description'></p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>179 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <button class="btn-hover color-7">BUTTON</button>
     <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('13', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м3.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Массажка</h2>
          <p class='description'></p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>179 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<button class="btn-hover color-7">BUTTON</button>
 </div>




You need to wrap your div.nft with the button in a wrapper div. You can then style it as you want (center it ..). Here I added some css to center buttons.


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper_div{        /*------added this to center button-------*/
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;

  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .tokenInfo{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      .price{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #ee83e5;
        font-weight: 700;
        ins{
          margin-left: -.3rem;
          margin-right: .5rem;
        }
      }
      .duration{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #a89ec9;
        margin-right: .2rem;
        ins{
          margin: .5rem;
          margin-bottom: .4rem;
        }
      }
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}
.buttons {
    margin: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-hover {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 55px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
    background-size: 300% 100%;

    border-radius: 50px;
    moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-hover:hover {
    background-position: 100% 0;
    moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-hover:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-hover.color-7 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6253e1, #852D91, #A3A1FF, #F24645);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(126, 52, 161, 0.75);
}
<div class="product-card-container">
  <div class="wrapper_div">
    <div class="nft"  onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м1.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Набор</h2>
          <p class='description'></p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>499 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<button class="btn-hover color-7">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper_div">
     <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('12', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м2.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Заяц</h2>
          <p class='description'></p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>179 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <button class="btn-hover color-7">BUTTON</button>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper_div">
     <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('13', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м3.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Массажка</h2>
          <p class='description'></p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>179 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<button class="btn-hover color-7">BUTTON</button>
</div>
 </div>



